# "System has been modified please contact the manufacturer, thank you!" message appears on the lock screen of SKK Mobile Prime

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, system-error

My phone is an SKK Mobile Prime on Android 4.2.2. I accidentally deleted my Android device manager and other folders on my phone that I thought were not useful at all. After that, this message appeared on my lock screen:

> System has been modified please contact the manufacturer, thank you!

I can't unlock my phone without having to touch the upper portion of the screen where it will show you the time, date, and the setting icon for your phone. So, after doing so, I tap the "back" button or "home" just to see the phone menu and do stuff. I know something on those deleted folders has something to do with this.

This has been my problem for 4 months already. I've been to different technicians, but all they do is charge me overprice.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Tip, in the future, don't delete system files. Especially when you don't know what they are.  I'm not sure based on your question how bad it is, but a factory reset will probably fix it.

Comment: @TristanWiley a factory reset never brings back system files, sorry. Please check our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for details.

Comment: Ah right, forgot about that Izzy. Although, reflashing the OS may work?

Answer (score 2):

There are only two ways out of this:

- restore the backup you (probably didn't) make before tampering with system files
- try to backup what you still can, and flash the system (either with the stock ROM for your device, or with any matching custom ROM, whatever you prefer. If you don't know where to get that, take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

For the future please note that everything you delete in `/system` will be gone for good. Always make a backup before you play there – and make yourself familiar first with what you're up to do ;)